# How to filter a view to show current month

Tags: views

I am building a Church Management System. I have a contact type for individuals. One field they have is D.O.B. which is a date popup field.

I want to create a block that lists people and their D.O.B. and have it filtered to only show those whose birthdays are in the current month.

I created the block and have it showing the people and their D.O.B. but how do I get it to filter to show only the people in current month?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

in the view select filter type your dob field select apply then another popup opens in which you have to select "Date selection form element" as popup (Provided you have enabled the Date Popup module in [Date API](https://www.drupal.org/project/date) package) then "Filter granularity" by month select apply operator should be equal to and in front of that theirs a option select a date .. you have to select enter a relative date and in relative date type now.apply and save

Answer (score 0):

Go for "Filter criteria" section add a condition to compare with current month. But first you need custom format DOB field values.